# Grep for unescaped percentage signs

Tags: regex, grep, percentage

I'm trying to find a regex to catch unescaped percentage signs (escaped by appending a '%', making it '%%') in a strings.xml file.

For example, this is okay:

```
<string name="power_message">Battery %1$d%%</string>
<string name="new_alert">Alert from %s</string>
```

This is not okay:

```
<string name="power_message">Battery %1$d% %</string>
<string name="new_alert">Alert from % s</string>
```

I want to be able to run the grep from command line to quickly make sure our build won't fail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -P` (PCRE) you can do:

```
grep -P '(?<!%)%(?![a-zA-Z0-9%])' file.xml
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY2nB7/1)